# When to use constants instead of instance variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, instance, constants

I understand that instance variables are mean to be states, and constants are meant to be constant. Is there any reason (besides convention) to use a constant instead of an instance variable? Is there a memory/speed advantage to using constants?

Comment: Of course constants are meant to be constants. It is a tautology. It does not make sense to write that.

Comment: Given that you can change a constant in Ruby, it is not a tautology.

Comment: I see. You are using constant in two different ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few things to consider here:

- Will the value change within the life-cycle of an object?
- Will you need to override the value in sub-classes?
- Do you need to configure the value at run-time?

The best kind of constants are those that don't really change short of updating the software:

```
class ExampleClass
  STATES = %i[
    off
    on
    broken
  ].freeze
end
```

Generally you use these constants internally in the class and avoid sharing them. When you share them you're limited in how they're used. For example, if another class referenced `ExampleClass::STATES` then you can't change that structure without changing other code.

You can make this more abstract by providing an *interface*:

```
class ExampleClass
  def self.states
    STATES
  end
end
```

If you change the structure of that constant in the future you can always preserve the old behaviour:

```
class ExampleClass
  STATES = {
    on: 'On',
    off: 'Off',
    broken: 'Broken'
  }.freeze

  def self.states
    STATES.keys
  end
end
```

When you're talking about instance variables you mean things you can configure:

```
class ConfigurableClass
  INITIAL_STATE_DEFAULT = :off

  def self.initial_state
    @initial_state || INITIAL_STATE_DEFAULT
  end

  def self.initial_state=(value)
    @initial_state = value ? value.to_sym
  end
end
```

Constants are great in that they're defined once and used for the duration of the process, so technically they're faster. Instance variables are still pretty quick, and are often a necessity as illustrated above.

Comment: You can also use [Module#const_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set): `A.const_set('K','cat'); A.const_get('K') #=> "cat"`.

Comment: True, but you'll get all sorts of nasty warnings if you're trying to re-define a constant, so there's extra work to undefine, then redefine it, vs. just assigning a variable.

Comment: I'm not so sure if constants are actually faster _in Ruby_, as they are technically still variables - you can read and write them at runtime. In compiled languages the compiler could inline constants to speed things up, but in Ruby this would be harder.

Comment: @averell There's a small penalty incurred for a method call of any kind, but this penalty is shrinking with each version of Ruby released. For example, `attr_reader` generated methods are faster than an equivalent one coded by hand due to internal optimizations. In most circumstances this penalty is irrelevant, but it's worth knowing about.

Comment: @tadman - I thought we were talking about accessing instance variables vs. accessing constants, so no method calls involved in either case. I agree that there may be some optimization potential for constants, though.

Answer (score 0):

Constants, unlike instance variables, are global. And they will at least complain if you try to re-assign their value.

While there might be a theoretical difference in memory/speed, it will be irrelevant in practice.

Comment: Constants are global only if declared in the global context, otherwise they're scoped as usual.

Comment: Scope constants are still global variables, in the sense that they exist exactly once  the runtime (and are accessible from everywhere). Instance variables, on the other hand, exist per object and are only accessible through the object they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

You may not realize this, but classes and modules are considered constants.

```
pry(main)> Foo
NameError: uninitialized constant Foo
```

The best advice I can give as to when you should use constants are when they are exactly that, constant.  For example, if I was making a scope in rails to find all the of recent `Foo`s for instance, I would create a constant that shows what recent is.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  DAYS_TILL_OLD = 7.days

  scope :recent, -> { where "created_at > ?", DateTime.now - DAYS_TILL_OLD  }
end
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Modules (including classes) are not necessarily constants. `Class.new`, `a = Class.new`, `@a = Class.new`, `@@a = Class.new`, `$a = Class.new`.

Comment: Instances of classes are assigned to constants, but a class is not a constant itself.

Comment: @sawa `Class` is still a constant.  sure it can be assigned to a variable, but the class `Class` is still a constant.  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-c-constants.  "In the first form, returns an array of the names of all constants accessible from the point of call. This list includes the names of all modules and classes defined in the global scope."  Just try `Object.constants` to see for yourself.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Clases are constants defined on the global scope. Classes are constants.  Your first statement is correct, an instance of a class, or a class can be assigned to a constant.  But that has no bearing on whether or not a class is a constant or not.

Comment: Classes are just instances of the `Class` class. You can have classes which are not assigned to constants. `foo = Class.new` is perfectly valid; you can then instantiate it with `foo.new`, without there ever being a constant in play.

Comment: and `Class` class is a constant of Object.  Seriously, I am asking you to do `Object.constants` in the console, and look, you'll find `Class`

Comment: The `Class` class is assigned to the Class constant, yes. That doesn't mean that all classes are constants.

Comment: @ChrisHeald `foo = Class.new` is perfectly fine, I agree, but `Class` is still a constant.

Comment: @ChrisHeald http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html  "Lexically, the names of constants look like the names of local variables, except that they begin with a capital letter. By convention, most constants are written in all uppercase with underscores to separate words, LIKE_THIS. Ruby class and module names are also constants, but they are conventionally written using initial capital letters and camel case, LikeThis."

Comment: Yes, class _names_ are constants. Classes themselves are not.

Comment: Ok, I think we are on the same page, my semantics might have been confusing.  Cheers, good discussion @ChrisHeald